# I am using standard Cocoa APIs for creating a PDF from a NSView. The PDF opens fine in preview, but fails to open in Adobe apps. Any suggestion?

Tags: objective-c, pdf, cocoa

I am developing a macOS Cocoa App in Objective-C / Swift, and I am creating some PDF content from a view, specifically a WKWebView. My code is the following:

```
CGRect pdfPagerect = CGRectMake(0, 400, 1000, 200 + height);
        
NSData *data = [webView dataWithPDFInsideRect:pdfPagerect];
        
PDFDocument *doc = [[PDFDocument alloc] initWithData:data];

[doc writeToFile:@"/Users/<user>/Desktop/test.pdf"];
```

The resulting [file](https://github.com/alfonsotesauro/Test-PDF-file-created-with-Cocoa) opens fine in Apple Preview, but fails to open in other programs like acrobat reader or photoshop. Can somebody inspect the file and find out possibly what is wrong with it ? I have tried also several PDF online validators and they say that the PDF is corrupt.

Comment: i just stumbled into the same problem, though I'm using the older WebView. The PDF opens kind of fine in Acrobat, but with some pages missing and doesn't allow making notes. This has not been an issue pre-October, so I'm suspecting something has changed in either macOS or Adobe apps.